# не работает подключенный javascript файл

Tags: javascript, html, form, input

Есть фрагмент кода на html:

```html
<form class="check_in_form" method="post" action="registration.php" onsubmit="return Validate()" name="check_form">
  
  <p id="input_form">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Имя" size="28">
  </p>
  
</form>
```

Код на JavaScript проверяет корректность ввода, - для этого я получаю значение input вот так:

```
var fname = document.forms["check_form"]["fname"];
```

Если JavaScript написан после закрытого тега:  (в конце файла), все работает.

Я решил закинуть весь код на JavaScript в отдельный файл ".js" , подключил его к html файлу и все перестало работать.

Браузер пишет "TypeError: document.forms.check_form is undefined"

Я так понимаю ошибка в получение значения формы? Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему?

PS: изучаю JS недавно..

Comment: Заинтересовала фраза _если JavaScript написан после закрытого тега: (в конце файла), все работает._ У вас, случаем, код не исполняется сразу после загрузки страницы? Если исполняется, то код JS начинает выполняться еще до поялвения формы. Код уже пытается найти форму и, конечно, не находит --> _undefined_. Соответственно, если выделенная мной фраза означает, что все начинает работать, если переместить подключение JS файла в конец документа, то очевидно Вам необходимо ознакомиться с событием **onLoad**. Проверка у Вас вызывается по onsubmit, что возвращаете в функции проверки? _return false_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте к тегу `<script>` атрибут `defer`, например. Вот так:

```
<script src="path/script.js" defer>
```